# Regexp to determine if a sourcecode line is inside a function

Tags: regex, autoit

I have a given multi-line source code and a {line index}. I want to know, if a sourcecode line (let's say line 12 '$var3 = "bar") is enclosed by Func/EndFunc, and which function it's in. In this example, it's in "_MyFunction2".

```
$var1 = "Test"

Func _MyFunction()
    $var2 = 1234
EndFunc

$var3 = "foo"
_MyFunction()
_MyFunction2()

Func _MyFunction2()
    $var3 = "bar"
EndFunc

MsgBox(0,"",$var1)
```

The pattern I've build looks like this - replace "12" with the appropriate line number:

```
^(?m)(?:Func ([^(]+).+\n|.*\n){12}(?s)(?=(?:.(?<!Func))+EndFunc)
```

**Now my question is**: Is there a way to do it more elegant or performant? I feel like this regexp is very clumsy.

Comment: By enclosed you mean directly? Line above and next line, or do you want to know if it is a variable in local scope or global scope?

Comment: Basically I want to know whether a statement / sourcecode-line (not necessarily just a variable) is in Global or Local Scope. And if Local: in which function exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfourtunately, such a Regex alone would probably be way too complicated because of `#cs` and `#ce` among other things

Instead I suggest using `tidy.exe` parser tool. It can be found in SciTE's directory ("full" installation is required)

Usage:  `"tidy.exe" "yourScript.au3" /gen_doc`

It outputs parsed source code including functions, line numbers and variable list.
You should parse that output line-by-line:

- in variable list search for lines that start with `'#### '`
- for each variable parse its name and 'Dim' line number using a regexp
- now find the line with this number in the source listing section
- if the line does not start with `NNNNN  |` then variable is global scoped
- otherwise then search function list for a function with largest line number above variable's line number - this will be your function